# What's wrong with printf in my strcat code?

Tags: c, printf, strcat

I have made this program to emulate strcat functionality but there is an error with printf which I don't understand...

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *mystrcat(char *s1, char *s2);

int main(void)
{
    char *s1,*s2;
    s1="asdad";
    s2="asdad";
    s1=mystrcat(s1,s2);
    printf(s1);

    return 0;
}
char *mystrcat(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;s1[i]<'\0';i++) ;
    for(j=0;s2[j]!='\0';j++) s1[i+j]=s2[j];
    s1[i+j]='\0';
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: 2) There is no space in `s1` to hold the concatenated character string.

Comment: As an additional note, you probably shouldn't use `printf(s1)` but rather `puts(s1)` or `printf("%s\n", s1)`. In particular if the strings were not compile-time constants, using them as the format string of `printf` is a serious problem if they happen to contain format specifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that `s1` doesn't have enough space to append `s2` to it. You need the size of the buffer pointed to by `s1` to be at least `strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1` (the `+ 1` being the NUL terminator).

The second problem is that string literals are read-only. You assign `s1` from `"asdad"`, which creates a pointer to (potentially) read-only memory. Of course the first problem means that you wouldn't have enough space to append to the end even if it were writeable, but this is one of the common pitfalls in C and worth mentioning.

Third problem (already mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41130608/204883)) is that the comparison `s1[i] < '\0'` is wrong and you will not correctly find the length of `s1` since the loop will not run even a single iteration. The correct condition is the same as in your second loop, `!= '\0'`. (This masks problem 1 since then you are inadvertently overwriting `s1` from the beginning.)

Comment: Careful with "size of `s1`". Since `s1` is a `char *`, its size is independent of the object it points to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you plz be more specific as for how can I fix the second problem?

Comment: @Metalingus It will probably be solved by fixing problem 1, e.g., by making the `s1` in `main` an array of sufficient size (instead of a pointer), or by dynamically allocating `s1` after the required size is known.

Answer (score 4):

At least, `s1[i] < '\0'` is the same as `s1[i] < 0`, which is always false.

Comment: A `char` can be `signed`, which could make `s1[i] < 0` true, right?

Comment: FiddlingBits makes a very good point: the relational expression is incorrect, but not for the reason you specified. For example, `(int)(char)(-1)` results in -1 on my platform, not 255 as `(int)(unsigned char)(-1)` does. Similarly, another platform might result in 255 in the former case (or another value; not every implementation uses two's complement) while `(int)(signed char)(-1)` results in -1. Some compilers even support making `char` signed or unsigned via compiler flag. The signedness of `char` is left implementation-defined by the ISO C standard, so `s1[i] < 0` isn't always false.